# python-docx: Inserting a paragraph before a table

Tags: python, python-docx

In python-docx there is a [Paragraph method](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#paragraph-objects) for inserting a paragraph before another one:

```
p2 = p.insert_paragraph_before("hello", style='Normal')
```

Supposing the case we already have a saved docx document with a table in it, and we want **to insert a paragraph before the table**, e.g. an explanation. It is fairly easy to find tables with:

```
for table in document.tables:
    ...
```

Unfortunately, a `Table` object does not have an `insert_paragraph_before` method. How could one implement that?

Answer (score 6):

you can even do it in more simple way like this

```
> paragraph = document.add_paragraph('the text you want')
> table._element.addprevious(paragraph._p)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll be damned... There is a simple hack to solve that problem:

```
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph

def insert_paragraph_before(item, text, style=None):
    """
    Return a newly created paragraph, inserted directly before this
    item (Table, etc.).
    """
    p = CT_P.add_p_before(item._element)
    p2 = Paragraph(p, item._parent)
    p2.text = text
    p2.style = style
    return p2
```

The idea is that the method `CT_P.add_p_before` is agnostic: it does not really care whether the item is really a paragraph. It will work just as well on a `CT_Tbl` (table) element.

Basically, this hack consists in using a method written for a sibling class, which happens to work just as well on a instance of this one.

Comment: `from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P` and 
`from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph`

Comment: Thanks, I added the import clauses in the message.

Comment: This is not appending the table in the same line!! Can you please give a solution for appending table after word in  the same line.

Comment: Indeed it is not, but it was not the subject of the question. Replacing a paragraph is a different thing.