# Python docx: Inserting paragraph after a table

Tags: python, python-docx

If we have a saved docx with a table on it and we want to **insert a paragraph after the table**, how do we do that?

I understand that Tables can be easily found with

```
for table in document.tables:
    ...
```

[python-docx: Inserting a paragraph before a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025038/python-docx-inserting-a-paragraph-before-a-table) has solution for inserting a paragraph **before** a table. How could one implement a similar solution for inserting a paragraph **after** a table.

Unfortunately, the inner workings of the python-docx is complicate for me to understand being fairly new to programming.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can add the table before the paragraph ? :) Although I think similar to the `para._p` there should be a `table._t` or `table._element`. Do those not have a add_next type of function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick in your case:

```
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph

def table_insert_paragraph_after(table):
    """Return new `Paragraph` object inserted directly after `table`.

    `table` must already be immediately followed by a paragraph. So
    This won't work for a table followed by another table or a table
    at the end of the document.
    """
    p = table._tbl.getnext()
    paragraph = Paragraph(p, table._parent)
    return paragraph.insert_paragraph_before()

paragraph = table_insert_paragraph_after(table)
```